# Deallocating memory from stack and heap

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, allocation

How can I deallocate memory stored for an array of known size?

The code below prints 4 times "constructor called!" but only once "Destructor called!" does it mean that memory for the whole array has been deallocated?

```
class Box
{
   public:
      Box() { 
         cout << "Constructor called!" <<endl; 
      }
      ~Box() { 
         cout << "Destructor called!" <<endl; 
      }
};

int main( )
{
   Box myBoxArray[4];

   delete myBoxArray; // Delete array

   return 0;
}
```

However if I declare `myBoxArray` dynamically, as shown in code below, the destructor is called 4 times.

```
class Box
{
    public:
      Box() { 
         cout << "Constructor called!" <<endl; 
      }
      ~Box() { 
         cout << "Destructor called!" <<endl; 
      }
}; 

int main( )
{
   Box* myBoxArray = new Box[4];

   delete [] myBoxArray; // Delete array

   return 0;
}
```

Is there a point of deallocating non-dynamically allocated memory or better leave it to garbage collector?

Comment: Your first example sports undefined behavior. You can't call `delete` on something which wasn't `new`ed before.

Comment: There is no garbage collector in c++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not the question of *having point*. You simply can't deallocate memory which you didn't allocate.

```
delete [] myBoxArray; // Delete array
```

has Undefined Behavior (UB), where anything or nothing can happen.

You can only `delete` something which you did `new`, and you can only `delete[]` something which you did `new[]`. Any violations to this rule will make the program to misbehave.

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds :).

Comment: is there any way to delete from memory arays/variables that are not made with ``new``?

Comment: @AkkaJaworek: They're automatically deleted when execution exits the block they're declared in.

Comment: @AkkaJaworek, compiler takes care of this. It's automatic, so you do not have to think about it.

Comment: and what about global variables?

Comment: @AkkaJaworek, their destructors are called when program terminates normally.